# Are liquid watercolors better than tube or pan watercolors?

Tags: paint, watercolor

I was looking at liquid watercolors like the Hydrus line from Dr. Martin.  They have gotten rave reviews in magazines and websites but I need some personal feedback on liquid watercolors.

Are they any good?  What are their advantages?  Disadvantages?

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts. We try to avoid duplicate questions to collect all the answers in one post if possible. I already linked you to one former post that might answer your question and here's another one: [Intentionally letting watercolor paints dry before using them?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/3250/6316). If none of those answer your question, please [edit] your post to point out which aspect is still unclear to you or what you don't understand.

Comment: What you ask in this question is different from what was asked in the questions Elmy linked, but the answers in those seem to broadly address what you're asking.  Your edits focused your question better, but it isn't really clear how what you want to know is or isn't covered in the linked threads.  Can you add a few sentences to clarify what specifics you're looking for that aren't addressed in those threads?  That will help people provide the detail you need without repeating what doesn't.